# Only connect to authorised WI-FI networks

Tags: wifi, raspbian-jessie, pi-3b+

I would like to know a way to set up my Raspberry Pi in order to only connect to specific SSID. My purpose is to not connect to password free wi-fi networks when my Wi-Fi is going down. 
I am using Raspbian

Comment: The Pi will only connect to nominated or manually selected networks.

Answer (score 2):

If you [setup wifi in wpa_supplicant with default entries](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) it will only connect to the specified `SSID`. If there are different networks with the same `SSID` you can restrict access only to the mac address of the network with `BSSID`:

```
~$ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="testing"
    bssid=b8:0f:18:a9:97:b0
    psk="testingPassword"
}
```

To get the `BSSID` you can use this command:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep -P "^BSS|SSID:"
```

Comment: Should the value for the key "bssid" be quoted (i.e. `bssid="b8:0f:18:a9:97:b0"`)?

Comment: @Fabian No, `bssid` is not quoted. I successful use it unquoted in my home network.